# How to install Nvidia Geforce GTX 960 Driver

Tags: drivers

Im new to Ubuntu, eveything is working great so far, except i can't seem to install the right driver for my Nvidia Geforce GTX 960 SSC. I'm trying to play steam games and can't get the right driver. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

In the terminal (press Ctrl+Alt+T to open) run this

```
 sudo apt-get purge nvidia*  
 sudo reboot
```

This will remove any installed nvidia drivers.

Then install the new drivers

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-361
sudo reboot
```

Comment: Removing the open source nouveau drivers is not necessary and also  not recommended ... something can completely go wrong and damage the system. That's the reason why I removed this part from the answer and also to prevent downvotes for your otherwise good and useful instructions ... +1 from me ! :)

Comment: Awesome, that worked! I see now, it was using the open source nouvea driver and i wouldn't be able to get in a game it was so choppy.

Comment: I then get "Update frequency out of range" from my display...

Comment: This is out of date